# Create Keystone list object without initial dialog?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, keystonejs

Is there a way to create a Keystone List (Model) item such that the initial dialog is skipped during the creation?

I want to create the item on the detail page and enforce a lot of fields as required that would not work on the dialog like Files and TextArray.

I've tried setting

```
initial: false
```

And it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There's an `autocreate` option for lists that will skip the create dialog when the "new item" button is clicked; the catch is that it will have created, saved and loaded the item in order to render the details view.

So you won't be able to use the built in `required` functionality to validate the fields you want to have required; however, you could implement custom validation in a pre-save hook that was skipped for the initial save when the item is new, and enforces validation rules for subsequent saves.

Having said that, if you are using Keystone 4 (currently in beta) complex fields like `File` and `TextArray` now work as required fields in the create dialog; if you have any problems getting them to work as initial fields, please open an issue on keystone's github repo!